# Max of dates in rolling window of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Dataframe is like this:

```
ID    Start_dt
1    10/14/2018
1    10/24/2018
2    7/12/2018
```

I want to find the the max date from the current and previous row i.e.

```
df.Start_dt.rolling(window=1).max().shift(1).fillna(datetime.timedelta(0),unit='days')
```

I get the error that ops is not implemented on rolling.

Output like:

```
ID    Start_dt    New_col
1    10/14/2018    NAN
1    10/24/2018   10/24/2018
2    7/12/2018    10/24/2018
```

Comment: I didn't get **max date in previous row** part. Can you show us expected output?

Comment: Shouldn't the second row have 10/14/2018?

Comment: Okay, take a look at the answers below and see if any of them do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`Series.rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.max.html):

```
dts = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_dt'], errors='coerce')
df['New_col'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(dts.astype(int).rolling(2).max()).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))


   ID    Start_dt     New_col
0   1  10/14/2018         NaT
1   1  10/24/2018  10/24/2018
2   2   7/12/2018  10/24/2018
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but just one question, why have you taken rolling 2?

Comment: @Mysterious because you said to find the "max of the current AND previous row".

Comment: So does rolling=1 not give max of current and previous row?

Comment: @Mysterious No, rolling(2) will. rolling(1) is meaningless, it only looks at one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Start_dt']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start_dt'])
m=df['Start_dt'] > df['Start_dt'].shift()
df['new_col']=np.where(m,df['Start_dt'],df['Start_dt'].shift())

print(df)

#   ID  Start_dt    new_col
#0  1   2018-10-14  NaT
#1  1   2018-10-24  2018-10-24
#2  2   2018-07-12  2018-10-24
```

Comment: It does solve the problem but I don't think it can be extended for comparison of more than one row, right?

Comment: are you telling, you have more number of columns in your dataframe?